# Can't access to cloud9 remotly

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have installed Cloud 9 IDE on my server, but I can't access to it remotely.

```
info  - socket.io started
Project root is: .
Trying to start your browser in: http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Does Cloud 9 work only on local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default the Cloud9 webserver listens only to the localhost interface, to specify another address, just add the following argument to the command line: `-l 0.0.0.0`, e.g.

```
./cloud9.sh -l 0.0.0.0 -w ~/workspace
```